# Parsing csv file with missing entries

Tags: c, parsing, csv

I am trying to parse a csv file with C where the separator is `|` using `strtok`. The problem is that some fields are empty and thus two separators are placed next to each other. It seems that `strtok` is just skipping all empty fields and just outputting the next non-empty field.

The thing is that I need to know at which position the token that is being read belongs to.

Here is a very small example to illustrate.

FILE

```
node|171933|||traffic_signals|||||40.4200658|-3.7016652
```

This line for instance has 10 fields, but only field 1,2,9 and 10 have some value in it.

CODE

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h>

void main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    char lineBuf[128];
    char *token;
    int i=0;

    if((fp = fopen("test.txt", "r"))==NULL){
      fprintf (stderr, "\nError when opening file\n");
      return ;
    }

    fgets (lineBuf, sizeof(lineBuf), fp);

    token=strtok(lineBuf, "|\n");
    while(token!=NULL){
      printf("Element %d: %s\n",i,token); i++;
      token=strtok(NULL, "|\n");
    }
}
```

OUTPUT

```
Element 0: node
Element 1: 171933
Element 2: traffic_signals
Element 3: 40.4200658
Element 4: -3.7016652
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT

```
Element 0: node
Element 1: 171933
Element 4: traffic_signals
Element 9: 40.4200658
Element 10: -3.7016652
```

Is there any other way to parse a line like this as expected? The number of elements in a line is not defined previously.

I already know that the behaviour shown by `strtok` is the usual behaviour I am just asking for another way of doing it to obtain the desired results, not for the explanation of why this happens.

Comment: Because `strtok()` is designed to skip over multiple occurrences of the delimiter, it is not the correct tool for parsing CSV files. I suggest looking up [`strspn()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strspn.html) and (more particularly) [`strcspn()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strcspn.html). These are non-destructive (unlike `strtok()`) and can easily be made to do as you want.  (They're much less well known than, say, `strlen()`, but they've been standard C since the original standard.)

Comment: I've made `strcspn()` to tell me when the first `|` appears, still no clue on how to read the tokens or how to locate the positions of the other `|` in the string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure what platform you are on, but strsep() is the recommended replacement for what you are trying to do.

man [strsep](http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/LSB_3.0.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/baselib-strsep-3.html)

```
while (fgets(buf, BUFSIZE, fp) != NULL) {
    char *line  = buf;
    char *field;
    int index = 0;
    while ((field = strsep(&line, "|")) != NULL) {
        /* note the trailing field will contain newline. */
        printf("element %d = %s\n", index, field);
        index++;
   }
}
```

Comment: "The strsep() function was introduced as a replacement for strtok(), since the latter cannot handle empty fields." Chosen for simplicity.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

//non skip version strtok
char *my_strtok_r(char *str, const char *delims, char **store){
    char *p, *wk;
    if(str != NULL){
        *store = str;
    }
    if(*store == NULL) return NULL;
    //*store += strspn(*store, delims);//skip delimiter
    if(**store == '\0') return NULL;
    p=strpbrk(wk=*store, delims);
    if(p != NULL){
        *p='\0';
        *store = p + 1;
    } else {
        *store = NULL;
    }
    return wk;
}

char *my_strtok(char *str, const char *delims){
    static char *p;
    return my_strtok_r(str, delims, &p);
}

int main(void){
    char lineBuf[128] = "node|171933|||traffic_signals|||||40.4200658|-3.7016652\n";
    char *token;
    int i=0;

    token=my_strtok(lineBuf, "|\n");
    while(token!=NULL){
        if(*token)//token != "";
            printf("Element %d: %s\n",i,token); 
        i++;
        token=my_strtok(NULL, "|\n");
    }
    return 0;    
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. This works better than most C parsing csv libraries I have found.

Comment: @cokedude This is just another implementation of `strsep`. When handling CSV, use something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45965198/971127). FYI:[RFC4180](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180)

Comment: Will your longer version in the link you provided handle the missing entry case? That is how I found your shorter version on this page. What is better about your longer version? Will it handle more annoying and complicated cases? Why is it not letting me @bluepixy like it usually does?

Comment: @cokedude Long versions allow separators and newline in strings. It is necessary as a format as CSV (See RFC4180 link in previous comment). Of course, if it is assumed that such notation is not included, you can simply use the method like this article (or use `strsep`).