# Reading and Saving Values from a CSV using C with Dynamic Allocation

Tags: c, arrays, csv

EDITS ON THE BOTTOM (I wrote this as an edit rather than its own question because it is so related):

I am writing a CSV reader that should save all the values as characters in a large, multidimensional array. In previous posts I have been warned about being either too vague with my condensed code, so I am going to post more of it. I want to apologize for its length, as I am still trying to gauge what an appropriate length looks like on this site.

Eventually this program will become the headliner in a Header File I am creating to perform data analysis. Header Files I use for this program are:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
```

The problem I am having is that the reader appears to work within the function called read_csv(). I know this because of the printf() statements placed within that function. When I printf() the multidimensional, character array 'buffer' in main(), the data does not appear correctly.

In main(), the first column will print correctly, but the next three will not. Also, my goal is to be able to read any MxN CSV file with cells carrying a MAXIMUM of 20 Characters. Creating generalized code using malloc() is my next goal in this task.

My main() is structured like:

```
int main(){

  FILE *f;
  char fname[20];
  int i, j;

  printf("enter name of csv file : ") ;
  scanf("%s",fname) ;       

  f = fopen(fname, "r");

  //find row/col
  int find_c_r[2];
  int * pfrc = &find_c_r[0];
  pfrc = find_col_row(f);
  printf("Find_c_r[0] = %d \t Find_c_r[1] = %d\n", *pfrc, *(pfrc+1));

  int numCol = *pfrc;
  int numRow = *(pfrc+1);

  char buffer[50][50][20];// ideally size buffer[numCol][numRow][20]

  //sets all values to NULL
  for(j = 0 ; j < 50 ; j++){
    for(i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++){   
      memset(buffer[i][j],'\0', 20);
    }
  }

  read_csv(f, numCol, numRow, buffer); 
  /////
  printf("\n\n");

 for(j = 0 ; j < numRow ; j++){
    for(i = 0 ; i < numCol; i++){      
      printf("[%d][%d]",i, j);
      printf("_%s_  ",buffer[i][j]);
    } 
    printf("\n");
  }

  printf("END OF PROGRAM.\n");
 }
```

One part of this is dynamic allocation of my array 'buffer'. I'm not quite sure how to malloc() in this format.

The first function main() calls is find_col_row(FILE *f). It is working without a problem, but folks have requested more of my code in questions. It returns a pointer to an int array which holds the number of Columns and Rows in the CSV File being read:

```
int * find_col_row(FILE *f){
 //Find numCol and numRow
  int numCol, numRow;
  char c;
  int new_line= 0;
  int comma = 0;
  int z = 0;
  numCol = 0;
  numRow = 0;
  while (c != EOF) {
    c = fgetc(f) ; 
    if(c == ','){ //WORDS MUST BE SEPARATED BY COMMAS
      comma++;
    }
    if(c == ';'){ //LINES MUST BE SEPARATED BY SEMI-COLONS
      new_line++;
      if(numCol == 0){
         numCol = comma + 1;
      }
    } 
  }


  numRow = new_line - 1;

  int a[2] = {numCol, numRow};
  int * pa = &a[0];

  return pa;
}
```

The second function being called is read_csv(...). The goal of this function is to 'read' the CSV file and 'save' values of each cell in the multidimensional, character array 'buffer':

```
void read_csv(FILE *f, int numCol, int numRow, char buffer[numCol][numRow][20])  //cells split by ',', row split by ';'
{
  char fname[100];
  int i = 0, j = 0;
  int c = 0,n = 0, z = 0;

  if (f == NULL) {
    printf("can't open file, %s\n", fname) ;
    exit(1) ;
  }

  n = 0 ;

  fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET); //starts reading the file from the start
  c = fgetc(f) ;

  i = 0;
  j = 0;


  char temp[20];
  memset(temp, '\0', 20);
  int tc = 0; //temp counter
  int mv_temp = 0; //this aids in removing the first character if == ' '
  temp[tc] = c;
  while (c != EOF) {

    if(c == ','){
      if(temp[0] == ' '){
         for(mv_temp = 0 ; mv_temp < tc ; mv_temp++){
           temp[mv_temp] = temp[mv_temp + 1];
         }
      }
      strncpy(buffer[i][j], temp, 20);
      i++; 
      tc = 0;
      memset(temp, '\0', 20);
    }else if(c == ';'){
      if(temp[0] == ' '){
         for(mv_temp = 0 ; mv_temp < tc ; mv_temp++){
           temp[mv_temp] = temp[mv_temp + 1];
         }
      }
      strncpy(buffer[i][j], temp, 20);
      j++;
      i = 0;
      tc = 0;
      memset(temp, '\0', 20);
       c = fgetc(f);

    }else{
      temp[tc] = c;
      tc++;
    }
    c = fgetc(f);    
  }  /////while loop over


  for(j = 0 ; j < numRow ; j++){
    for(i = 0 ; i < numCol; i++){      
      printf("[%d][%d]",i, j);
      printf("_%s_  ",buffer[i][j]);
    } 
    printf("\n");
  }

}
```

Having not tried to run this program with any other CSV file, here is the CSV I use. When running the program, the first step will be to scanf() the name of the file. I call it

```
simp.csv
```

For reference, this data refers to basic American Football data: Formation, Formation Variation, Down, Distance. The file looks like:

```
OFF_FORM,FORM_VAR, DN, DIST;
DEUCE,RIGHT, 1, 10;
DEUCE,LEFT, 2, 7;
TRIO,RIGHT, 3, 3;
TREY,LEFT, 1, 10;
TRIO,RODDY, 1, 10;
TREY,LION, 2, 3;
DEEP,LEFT, 1, 10;
DEUCE,LION, 2, 15;
DEUCE,RIGHT, 3, 4;
DEEP,RODDY, 1, 10;
TREY,RIGHT, 1, 10;
TRIO,RAM, 2, 8;
TRIO,RAM, 3, 8;
DEEP,ROCK, 1, 10;
DEUCE,LION, 1, 10;
TRIO,LOUIE, 1, 10;
TRIO,RIGHT, 2,4;
DEUCE,RIGHT, 3, 6;
DEUCE,LION, 4, 2;
TREY,LION,1,10;
```

Again, I apologize for the length of the question. I hope I have enough information given to allow help to come. As a young/novice programmer, I am open to any and all feedback. If you can answer my question and point out ways to optimize my code to work more efficiently, I would greatly appreciate that feedback.

////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////

EDITS:

The code that @BLUEPIXY shared in their answer worked perfectly. Now, I am just trying to turn it into a basic header file and I am not sure of how to amend some of the problems I am seeing. All I did to the code was change the name of the functions and transfer them into a header file.

```
#ifndef bp_csv_reader
#define bp_csv_reader    

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <ctype.h>

//https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180
char *csv_get_field(FILE *fp, char separator, int *state)

char ***csv_read(const char *filename, size_t *rows, size_t *cols)

char *csv_trim(char *s)

#endif
```

csv.c looks like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "csv.h"

//https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180
char *csv_get_field(FILE *fp, char separator, int *state){
    int ch = fgetc(fp);

    if(ch == EOF)
        return NULL;

    size_t size = 1, index = 0;
    char *field = malloc(size);
    bool quoted_in = false;

    for(;ch != EOF; ch = fgetc(fp)){
        if(ch == '"'){
            if(quoted_in){
                int prefetch = fgetc(fp);
                if(prefetch == '"'){
                    ch = prefetch;
                } else {
                    quoted_in = false;
                    ungetc(prefetch, fp);
                    continue;
                }
            } else {
                quoted_in = true;
                continue;
            }
        } else if(!quoted_in && (ch == separator || ch == '\n')){
            break;
        }
        field[index++] = ch;
        char *temp = realloc(field, ++size);
        if(!temp){
            perror("realloc:");
            free(field);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        field = temp;
    }
    field[index] = 0;
    *state = ch;
    if(quoted_in){
        fprintf(stderr, "The quotes is not closed.\n");
        free(field);
        return NULL;
    }
    return field;
}

char ***csv_read(const char *filename, size_t *rows, size_t *cols){
    *rows = *cols = 0;

    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if(!fp){
        fprintf(stderr, "%s can't open in %s\n", filename, __func__);
        perror("fopen");
        return NULL;
    }


    char *field;
    int state;
    size_t r = 0, c = 0;
    char ***mat = NULL;
    void *temp;

    while(field = csv_get_field(fp, ',', &state)){
        if(c == 0){
            mat = realloc(mat, (r + 1)*sizeof(*mat));
            if(!mat){
                fprintf(stderr, "realloc failed in %s\n", __func__);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            mat[r] = NULL;
        }
        mat[r] = realloc(mat[r], (c + 1)*sizeof(**mat));
        if(!mat[r]){
            fprintf(stderr, "realloc failed in %s\n", __func__);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        mat[r][c++] = field;
        if(state == '\n' || state == EOF){
            if(*cols == 0){
                *cols = c;
            } else if(c != *cols){
                fprintf(stderr, "line %zu doesn't match number of columns in %s\n", r, filename);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            c  = 0;
            *rows = ++r;
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);

    return mat;
}

#include <ctype.h>

char *csv_trim(char *s){
    if(!s || !*s)
        return s;

    char *from, *to;

    for(from = s; *from && isspace((unsigned char)*from); ++from);
    for(to = s; *from;){
        *to++ = *from++;
    }
    *to = 0;
    while(s != to && isspace((unsigned char)to[-1])){
        *--to = 0;
    }
    return s;
}
```

And the code calling it looks like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <csv.h>


int main(void){
    size_t rows, cols;


    char ***mat = csv_read("simp.csv", &rows, &cols);

    size_t r, c;

    for(r = 0; r < rows; ++r){
        for(c = 0; c < cols; ++c){
            if(c)
                putchar(',');
            printf("%s", csv_trim(mat[r][c]));
            free(mat[r][c]);
        }
        puts("");
        free(mat[r]);
    }
    free(mat);
    return 0;
}
```

I am not sure why I am running into the errors I am running into. The code I got ran perfectly in its own file. The problems didn't arise until I placed them into a header file. This is how I compile int he terminal:

```
 acom test_csv.c csv.c -I. csv.h
```

And these are the Errors I see.

```
In file included from test_cesv.c:5:0:
./csv.h: In function ‘csv_get_field’:
./csv.h:15:1: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘char’
 char *csv_trim(char *s)
 ^
test_cesv.c:142:1: error: expected ‘{’ at end of input
 }
 ^
In file included from csv.c:5:0:
csv.h: In function ‘csv_get_field’:
csv.h:15:1: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘char’
 char *csv_trim(char *s)
 ^
csv.c:55:67: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘{’ token
 char ***csv_read(const char *filename, size_t *rows, size_t *cols){
                                                                   ^
csv.c:105:24: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘{’ token
 char *csv_trim(char *s){
                        ^
csv.c:120:1: error: expected ‘{’ at end of input
 }
 ^
csv.h: In function ‘csv_get_field’:
csv.h:15:1: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘char’
 char *csv_trim(char *s)
 ^
```

Comment: 1) at `find_col_row` : `int a[2] = {numCol, numRow};
  int * pa = &a[0];  return pa;` : It returns the address of the local auto variable.  It is invalidated outside the scope of the function. 2) `char c; ... while (c != EOF) {` : `char c:` --> `int c:` For comparison with `EOF` you need to use `int`.

Comment: 3) `read_csv(f, numCol, numRow, buffer);` doesn't match `char buffer[50][50][20];` 4) `i < 10 ;` --> `i < 50 ;`

Comment: 5) `numRow = new_line - 1;` : If `-1` means that you do not include the first line as the field name of the CSV file, you must do so in `read_csv` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

//https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180
char *getCSVField(FILE *fp, char separator, int *state){
    int ch = fgetc(fp);

    if(ch == EOF)
        return NULL;

    size_t size = 1, index = 0;
    char *field = malloc(size);
    bool quoted_in = false;

    for(;ch != EOF; ch = fgetc(fp)){
        if(ch == '"'){
            if(quoted_in){
                int prefetch = fgetc(fp);
                if(prefetch == '"'){
                    ch = prefetch;
                } else {
                    quoted_in = false;
                    ungetc(prefetch, fp);
                    continue;
                }
            } else {
                quoted_in = true;
                continue;
            }
        } else if(!quoted_in && (ch == separator || ch == '\n')){
            break;
        }
        field[index++] = ch;
        char *temp = realloc(field, ++size);
        if(!temp){
            perror("realloc:");
            free(field);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        field = temp;
    }
    field[index] = 0;
    *state = ch;
    if(quoted_in){
        fprintf(stderr, "The quotes is not closed.\n");
        free(field);
        return NULL;
    }
    return field;
}

char ***read_csv(const char *filename, size_t *rows, size_t *cols){
    *rows = *cols = 0;

    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if(!fp){
        fprintf(stderr, "%s can't open in %s\n", filename, __func__);
        perror("fopen");
        return NULL;
    }

    char *field;
    int state;
    size_t r = 0, c = 0;
    char ***mat = NULL;
    void *temp;

    while(field = getCSVField(fp, ',', &state)){
        if(c == 0){
            mat = realloc(mat, (r + 1)*sizeof(*mat));
            if(!mat){
                fprintf(stderr, "realloc failed in %s\n", __func__);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            mat[r] = NULL;
        }
        mat[r] = realloc(mat[r], (c + 1)*sizeof(**mat));
        if(!mat[r]){
            fprintf(stderr, "realloc failed in %s\n", __func__);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        mat[r][c++] = field;
        if(state == '\n' || state == EOF){
            if(*cols == 0){
                *cols = c;
            } else if(c != *cols){
                fprintf(stderr, "line %zu doesn't match number of columns in %s\n", r, filename);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            c  = 0;
            *rows = ++r;
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);

    return mat;
}

#include <ctype.h>

char *trim(char *s){
    if(!s || !*s)
        return s;

    char *from, *to;

    for(from = s; *from && isspace((unsigned char)*from); ++from);
    for(to = s; *from;){
        *to++ = *from++;
    }
    *to = 0;
    while(s != to && isspace((unsigned char)to[-1])){
        *--to = 0;
    }
    return s;
}

int main(void){
    size_t rows, cols;
    char ***mat = read_csv("simp.csv", &rows, &cols);
    for(size_t r = 0; r < rows; ++r){
        for(size_t c = 0; c < cols; ++c){
            if(c)
                putchar(',');
            printf("%s", trim(mat[r][c]));
            free(mat[r][c]);
        }
        puts("");
        free(mat[r]);
    }
    free(mat);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. I was getting an error that said something about a c99 mode with the lines that read:

     for(size_t r = 0; r < rows; ++r){
             for(size_t c = 0; c < cols; ++c){

But all I needed to do was declare size_t r, c; outside of the loop and it ran just fine. 

Runs perfectly. Unfortunately I have to get to work right now, but I look forward to digging into it later. I haven't scanned it yet, but what would it do if a cell were blank or just contained a space? Suppose the data was incomplete rather than a perfect MxN.

Comment: @MDR _cell were blank_ E.g like `,,` ==> `""`. _just contained a space_ `"  "` ==> apply `trim` ==> `""`. _incomplete rather than a perfect MxN._ `fprintf(stderr, "line %zu doesn't match number of columns in %s\n", r, filename); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);`

Comment: I tried running your code through a header file and am running into an error I've never seen before. It happens in a few places. Do you have a suggestion? ----------------------csv.h: In function ‘csv_get_field’:
csv.h:15:1: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘char’
 char *csv_trim(char *s)
 ^

Comment: @MDR I think that there is a typo such as forgetting to write `;` in the header file.

Comment: that's exactly what it was. Rookie mistake. I appreciate your help with this. I'm not sure I could have written such elegant code.

Comment: sorry about that. Big Check Mark. (I'm still getting used to the expectations of this site.)